# py.test timeout/keepalive/heartbeat?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, codeship

I'm attempting to add a test to my unit tests that is significantly more complicated and takes longer to perform. The idea would be to run this longer test infrequently. However, the test itself takes longer than the 10 minute timeout that codeship currently has, and since it doesn't fail/pass within 10 minutes my codeship will show as failing.

Is there any way to get py.test to print out a heartbeat or something every x minutes to keep codeship happy? Obviously any of my output and logging gets gobbled up by py.test itself, so that isn't helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure If I understood your question correctly but if your concern was gobbling of output by Py.Test they run the pytest using -s option.